# What do Clustered and Non-Clustered index actually mean?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I have a limited exposure to DB and have only used DB as an application programmer. I want to know about `Clustered` and `Non clustered indexes`.
I googled and what I found was :

> *A clustered index is a special type of index that reorders  the way
>   records in the table are physically
>   stored.  Therefore table can have only
>   one clustered index. The leaf  nodes
>   of a clustered index contain the data
>   pages. A nonclustered index is a
>   special type of index in which  the
>   logical order of the index does not
>   match the physical  stored order of
>   the rows on disk. The leaf node of a 
>   nonclustered index does not consist of
>   the data pages.  Instead, the leaf
>   nodes contain index rows.*

What I found in SO was [What are the differences between a clustered and a non-clustered index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91688/what-are-the-differencespros-cons-between-clustered-and-non-clustered-indexes).

Can someone explain this in plain English?

Comment: These two videos  ([Clustered vs. Nonclustered Index Structures in SQL Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITcOiLSfVJQ&t=139s&ab_channel=VoluntaryDBA) and [Database Design 39 - Indexes (Clustered, Nonclustered, Composite Index)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ3jBam2IEA&ab_channel=CalebCurry) )  are more helpful than a plain text answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1286, accepted):

With a clustered index the rows are stored physically on the disk in the same order as the index. Therefore, there can be only one clustered index.

With a non clustered index there is a second list that has pointers to the physical rows. You can have many non clustered indices, although each new index will increase the time it takes to write new records.

It is generally faster to read from a clustered index if you want to get back all the columns. You do not have to go first to the index and then to the table.

Writing to a table with a clustered index can be slower, if there is a need to rearrange the data.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "physically".

Comment: physically as in the actual bits stored on the disk

Comment: “There can therefore be only one clustered index.”: I don't see the point, and SQL shows every day you can order on multiple indexes or columns. By the way, a complementary question: I heard to say with MS‑SQL server, a primary key always defines a clustered index… is it true with other databases as well?

Comment: Refer to [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186342.aspx) "When you create a PRIMARY KEY constraint,  a unique clustered index on the column or columns is automatically created **if** a clustered index on the table does not already exist", which means it's not necessary have to be the same column.

Comment: @Pete that isn't the case. SQL Server certainly doesn't guarantee that all data files are laid out in a contiguous physical area of disc and there is zero file system fragmentation. It isn't even true that a clustered index is in order within the data file. The degree to which this isn't the case is the degree of logical fragmentation.

Comment: I have an index with very high fragmentation 98% - what is the recommended action - regular maintenance?

Comment: Just a quick comment to back up Martin Smith's point - clustered indexes do not guarantee sequential storage on the disk. Managing exactly where data is placed on the disk is the job of the OS, not the DBMS. But it suggests that items are ordered generally according to the clustering key. What this means is that if the DB grows by 10GB, for instance, the OS may decide to put that 10GB in 5x2GB chunks on different parts of the disk. A clustered table covering the 10GB will be stored sequentially on each 2GB chunk, those 2GB chunks MAY NOT be sequential however.

Comment: I know this is late but this video give a nice graphical explanation. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITcOiLSfVJQ

Comment: Anyone who reads this answer should scroll down to @Martin Smith's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24470091/3002584) and see why claiming that `With a clustered index, the rows are stored physically on the disk in the same order as the index` is simply wrong.

Comment: Ok the idea is relatively clear, but when to non clustered index?

Comment: Umm, why _it is generally faster to read from a clustered index if you want to get back all the columns_ ? Maybe you meant _all the rows_ ?

Comment: Downvoted for confusing/inaccurate use of "physically on the disk".

Comment: Upvoted for using technically inaccurate but easily understood simplification to explain the concept in "plain English". When someone asks for a simplified explanation, nit-picking technical details is counterproductive.

Answer (score 625):

A clustered index means you are telling the database to store close values actually close to one another on the disk. This has the benefit of rapid scan / retrieval of records falling into some range of clustered index values.

For example, you have two tables, Customer and Order:

```
Customer
----------
ID
Name
Address

Order
----------
ID
CustomerID
Price
```

If you wish to quickly retrieve all orders of one particular customer, you may wish to create a clustered index on the "CustomerID" column of the Order table. This way the records with the same CustomerID will be physically stored close to each other on disk (clustered) which speeds up their retrieval.

P.S. The index on CustomerID will obviously be not unique, so you either need to add a second field to "uniquify" the index or let the database handle that for you but that's another story.

Regarding multiple indexes. You can have only one clustered index per table because this defines how the data is physically arranged. If you wish an analogy, imagine a big room with many tables in it. You can either put these tables to form several rows or pull them all together to form a big conference table, but not both ways at the same time. A table can have other indexes, they will then point to the entries in the clustered index which in its turn will finally say where to find the actual data.

Comment: That being said CI should be always used for PK

Comment: So with a clustered index is it the records in the index or the table that are stored close together?

Comment: @Caltor **The table.** The index is ordered by definition. For example, a btree would be ordered so that one can simply do address arithmetic to search. The idea of the cluster is to cater the table to the performance of a particular index. To be clear, the records of the table will be reordered to match the order **that the index is originally in**.

Comment: @Caltor Not at all! Indeed, the documentation and the name itself are quite misleading. Having a "clustered index" really has quite little to do with the index. Conceptually, what you really have is "a table clustered on index _x_".

Comment: @user151323, a second field to «uniquify» the index can be a date and time?

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez: Sure, you can use almost any that's stored in-row, so no `XML`, `VARCHAR(MAX)`, or `VARBINARY(MAX)`.  Note that it usually makes sense to cluster on the date field *first*, as a clustered index is most efficient for range scans, which are most common on date types.  YMMV.

Comment: This sentence sold me the concept in a second! thanks *"If you wish to quickly retrieve all orders of one particular customer, you may wish to create a clustered index on the "CustomerID" column of the Order table ...... physically stored close to each other on disk (clustered) which speeds up their retrieval."*

Answer (score 359):

In SQL Server, row-oriented storage both clustered and nonclustered indexes are organized as B trees.

[image]

([Image Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443(v=sql.105).aspx))

The key difference between clustered indexes and non clustered indexes is that the leaf level of the clustered index **is** the table. This has two implications.

1. The rows on the clustered index leaf pages always contain *something* for each of the (non-sparse) columns in the table (either the value or a pointer to the actual value).
2. The clustered index is the primary copy of a table.

Non clustered indexes can also do point 1 by using the `INCLUDE` clause (Since SQL Server 2005) to explicitly include all non-key columns but they are secondary representations and there is always another copy of the data around (the table itself).

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
A INT,
B INT,
C INT,
D INT
)

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ci ON T(A, B)
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nci ON T(A, B) INCLUDE (C, D)
```

The two indexes above will be nearly identical. With the upper-level index pages containing values for the key columns `A, B` and the leaf level pages containing `A, B, C, D`

> There can be only one clustered index per table, because the data rows
> themselves can be sorted in only one order.

The above quote from SQL Server books online causes much confusion

In my opinion, it would be much better phrased as.

> There can be only one clustered index per table because the leaf level rows of the clustered index **are** the table rows.

The book's online quote is not incorrect but you should be clear that the "sorting" of both non clustered and clustered indices is logical, not physical. If you read the pages at leaf level by following the linked list and read the rows on the page in slot array order then you will read the index rows in sorted order but physically the pages may not be sorted. The commonly held belief that with a clustered index the rows are always stored physically on the disk in the same order as the index **key** is false.

This would be an absurd implementation. For example, if a row is inserted into the middle of a 4GB table SQL Server does **not** have to copy 2GB of data up in the file to make room for the newly inserted row.

Instead, a page split occurs. Each page at the leaf level of both clustered and non clustered indexes has the address (`File: Page`) of the next and previous page in logical key order. These pages need not be either contiguous or in key order.

e.g. the linked page chain might be `1:2000 <-> 1:157 <-> 1:7053`

When a page split happens a new page is allocated from anywhere in the filegroup (from either a mixed extent, for small tables or a non-empty uniform extent belonging to that object or a newly allocated uniform extent). This might not even be in the same file if the filegroup contains more than one.

The degree to which the logical order and contiguity differ from the idealized physical version is the degree of logical fragmentation.

In a newly created database with a single file, I ran the following.

```
CREATE TABLE T
  (
     X TINYINT NOT NULL,
     Y CHAR(3000) NULL
  );

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix
  ON T(X);

GO

--Insert 100 rows with values 1 - 100 in random order
DECLARE @C1 AS CURSOR,
        @X  AS INT

SET @C1 = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT number
    FROM   master..spt_values
    WHERE  type = 'P'
           AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 100
    ORDER  BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)

OPEN @C1;

FETCH NEXT FROM @C1 INTO @X;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO T (X)
      VALUES        (@X);

      FETCH NEXT FROM @C1 INTO @X;
  END
```

Then checked the page layout with

```
SELECT page_id,
       X,
       geometry::Point(page_id, X, 0).STBuffer(1)
FROM   T
       CROSS APPLY sys.fn_PhysLocCracker( %% physloc %% )
ORDER  BY page_id
```

The results were all over the place. The first row in key order (with value 1 - highlighted with an arrow below) was on nearly the last physical page.

[image]

Fragmentation can be reduced or removed by rebuilding or reorganizing an index to increase the correlation between logical order and physical order.

After running

```
ALTER INDEX ix ON T REBUILD;
```

I got the following

[image]

If the table has no clustered index it is called a heap.

Non clustered indexes can be built on either a heap or a clustered index. They always contain a row locator back to the base table. In the case of a heap, this is a physical row identifier (rid) and consists of three components (File:Page: Slot). In the case of a Clustered index, the row locator is logical (the clustered index key).

For the latter case if the non clustered index already naturally includes the CI key column(s) either as NCI key columns or `INCLUDE`-d columns then nothing is added. Otherwise, the missing CI key column(s) silently gets added to the NCI.

SQL Server always ensures that the key columns are unique for both types of indexes. The mechanism in which this is enforced for indexes not declared as unique differs between the two index types, however.

Clustered indexes get a `uniquifier` added for any rows with key values that duplicate an existing row. This is just an ascending integer.

For non clustered indexes not declared as unique SQL Server silently adds the row locator into the non clustered index key. This applies to all rows, not just those that are actually duplicates.

The clustered vs non clustered nomenclature is also used for column store indexes. The paper [Enhancements to SQL Server Column Stores](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=193599) states

> Although column store data is not really "clustered" on any key, we
> decided to retain the traditional SQL Server convention of referring
> to the primary index as a clustered index.

Comment: Although your explanation for `With a clustered index the rows are stored physically on the disk in the same order as the index` is a false statement is convincing, almost all articles/blogs/database administrators claim that in clustered index, rows are physically sorted and stored contiguously

Comment: @brainstorm yes I'm aware of that. Probably that is because of the phrasing on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx) but to see that the phrasing there is somewhat misleading you just need to look at the [fragmentation topics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966523.aspx#EHAA)

Comment: @brainstorm: It's amazing how some false statements get repeated as gospel.  A clustered indicates that, at least from the perspective of sequential reads, *it would be "desirable" to have the rows stored physically on disk in the same order as the index*, but that's a far cry from saying that it will cause them to actually be stored in such a fashion.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have reproduced and confirmed the results of your test on `SQL Server 2014`. I get `95%` fragmentation of the index after the initial insert. After `index rebuild` the fragmentation was `0%` and the values were ordered. I am wondering, can we say that `The only time the data rows in a table are stored in sorted order is when its clustered index fragmentation is 0`?

Comment: @gotqn Fragmentation also covers contiguity but basically yes.

Comment: Great explanation, the visual part helped the understanding ! Just one question, the horizontal numbers mean the page right ? So as close the page numbers are for the register the better ?

Comment: @Terkhos yes, the horizontal numbers are the page and the vertical ones the index key. The second graph has entirely different page numbers showing the rebuild used a new area later in the file. A perfectly unfragmented index would use contiguous pages in key order. Which the second graph is pretty close to.

Comment: @MartinSmith,this may be long question,but it helped me understand fragmentation,when i use spatial results as mentioned ,i am not able to see dots as shown in your image,can you please help understand ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar - You might need to increase the number from `1` in `STBuffer(1)` if the pages cover a much wider range than they do in my example.

Comment: @TheGameiswar - And you might need to boost it by quite a lot. Even into the thousands depending on how far apart the page numbers are. e.g. http://i.stack.imgur.com/SPtUD.png. So it could be improved by applying a scaling factor so that X and Y axis are both 1-100 based on min and max actual values.

Comment: @MartinSmith Now, Sir, this is an answer. I'd love to see it on top of the responses list but as SO goes, "quick and simple" gets the upvoting.

Comment: @vaitrafra - Thanks. This answer is 5 years younger than some on this page which hasn't helped the positioning.

Comment: @MartinSmith Appreciate that you provided the graphics and the command to rebuild the index.

Comment: It's a great answer but the question specifically said "in plain English". To me this implies they were after a high level explanation described simply (as the top answer is).

Comment: @Manachi this answer was given 5 years after the original question was asked. The purpose of it is to correct some misleading aspects of those answers. The (now 8 year old) whims of the OP are not a concern of mine. Other readers may appreciate a lower level view.

Comment: Oh my, that `sys.fn_PhysLocCracker` function is brilliant for visualising what the hell is going on!

Answer (score 186):

I realize this is a very old question, but I thought I would offer an analogy to help illustrate the fine answers above.

### CLUSTERED INDEX

If you walk into a public library, you will find that the books are all arranged in a particular order (most likely the Dewey Decimal System, or DDS). This corresponds to the *"clustered index"* of the books. If the DDS# for the book you want was `005.7565 F736s`, you would start by locating the row of bookshelves that is labeled `001-099` or something like that. (This endcap sign at the end of the stack corresponds to an "intermediate node" in the index.) Eventually you would drill down to the specific shelf labelled `005.7450 - 005.7600`, then you would scan until you found the book with the specified DDS#, and at that point *you have found your book.*

### NON-CLUSTERED INDEX

But if you didn't come into the library with the DDS# of your book memorized, then you would need a second index to assist you. In the olden days you would find at the front of the library a wonderful bureau of drawers known as the "Card Catalog". In it were thousands of 3x5 cards -- one for each book, sorted in alphabetical order (by title, perhaps). This corresponds to the *"non-clustered index"*. These card catalogs were organized in a hierarchical structure, so that each drawer would be labeled with the range of cards it contained (`Ka - Kl`, for example; i.e., the "intermediate node"). Once again, you would drill in until you found your book, but in *this* case, once you have found it (i.e, the "leaf node"), you don't have the book itself, but just a card with an *index* number (the DDS#) with which you could find the actual book in the clustered index.

Of course, nothing would stop the librarian from photocopying all the cards and sorting them in a different order in a separate card catalog. (Typically there were at least two such catalogs: one sorted by author name, and one by title.) In principle, you could have as many of these "non-clustered" indexes as you want.

Comment: I could, perhaps, extend this analogy to describe **"Included" columns**, which can be used with Non-Clustered Indexes: One could imagine a card in the card catalog including more than just a single book, but instead a *list* of all the published versions of the book, organized numerically by publication date. Just like in an "included column" this information is stored only at the leaf level (thus reducing the number of cards the librarian must create).

Answer (score 74):

Find below some characteristics of clustered and non-clustered indexes:

### Clustered Indexes

1. Clustered indexes are indexes that uniquely identify the rows in an SQL table.
2. Every table can have exactly one clustered index.
3. You can create a clustered index that covers more than one column. For example: `create Index index_name(col1, col2, col.....)`.
4. By default, a column with a primary key already has a clustered index.

### Non-clustered Indexes

1. Non-clustered indexes are like simple indexes. They are just used for fast retrieval of data. Not sure to have unique data.

Comment: One slight correction to Point 1. A clustered index does *not* necessarily uniquely identify the rows in an SQL table. That's the function of a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @Nigel, a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE INDEX?

Answer (score 64):

**Clustered Index**

A clustered index determines the physical order of DATA in a table. For this reason, a table has only one clustered index(Primary key/composite key).

> "**Dictionary**" No need of any other Index, its already Index according to words

**Nonclustered Index**

A non-clustered index is analogous to an index in a Book. The data is stored in one place. The index is stored in another place and the index has pointers to the storage location. this help in the fast search of data. For this reason, a table has more than 1 Nonclustered index.

> "**Biology Book**" at starting there is a separate index to point Chapter location and At the "**END**" there is another Index pointing the common WORDS location

Answer (score 54):

A very simple, non-technical rule-of-thumb would be that clustered indexes are usually used for your primary key (or, at least, a unique column) and that non-clustered are used for other situations (maybe a foreign key). Indeed, SQL Server will by default create a clustered index on your primary key column(s). As you will have learnt, the clustered index relates to the way data is physically sorted on disk, which means it's a good all-round choice for most situations.

Answer (score 21):

### Clustered Index

A Clustered Index is basically a tree-organized table. Instead of storing the records in an unsorted Heap table space, the clustered index is actually B+Tree index having the Leaf Nodes, which are ordered by the clusters key column value, store the actual table records, as illustrated by the following diagram.

[image: Clustered Index]

The Clustered Index is the default table structure in SQL Server and MySQL. While MySQL adds a hidden clusters index even if a table doesn't have a Primary Key, SQL Server always builds a Clustered Index if a table has a Primary Key column. Otherwise, the SQL Server is stored as a Heap Table.

The Clustered Index can speed up queries that filter records by the clustered index key, like the usual CRUD statements. Since the records are located in the Leaf Nodes, there's no additional lookup for extra column values when locating records by their Primary Key values.

For example, when executing the following SQL query on SQL Server:

```
SELECT PostId, Title
FROM Post
WHERE PostId = ?
```

You can see that the Execution Plan uses a Clustered Index Seek operation to locate the Leaf Node containing the `Post` record, and there are only two logical reads required to scan the Clustered Index nodes:

```
|StmtText                                                                             |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|SELECT PostId, Title FROM Post WHERE PostId = @P0                                    |
|  |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([high_performance_sql].[dbo].[Post].[PK_Post_Id]), |
|     SEEK:([high_performance_sql].[dbo].[Post].[PostID]=[@P0]) ORDERED FORWARD)      | 

Table 'Post'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
```

### Non-Clustered Index

Since the Clustered Index is usually built using the Primary Key column values, if you want to speed up queries that use some other column, then you'll have to add a Secondary Non-Clustered Index.

The Secondary Index is going to store the Primary Key value in its Leaf Nodes, as illustrated by the following diagram:

[image: Non-Clustered Index]

So, if we create a Secondary Index on the `Title` column of the `Post` table:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_Post_Title on Post (Title)
```

And we execute the following SQL query:

```
SELECT PostId, Title
FROM Post
WHERE Title = ?
```

We can see that an Index Seek operation is used to locate the Leaf Node in the `IDX_Post_Title` index that can provide the SQL query projection we are interested in:

```
|StmtText                                                                      |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|SELECT PostId, Title FROM Post WHERE Title = @P0                              |
|  |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([high_performance_sql].[dbo].[Post].[IDX_Post_Title]),|
|     SEEK:([high_performance_sql].[dbo].[Post].[Title]=[@P0]) ORDERED FORWARD)|

Table 'Post'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0
```

Since the associated `PostId` Primary Key column value is stored in the `IDX_Post_Title` Leaf Node, this query doesn't need an extra lookup to locate the `Post` row in the Clustered Index.

Comment: Nice try, yet it misses the vital meaning: **table** data **ordering**. See the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described.

> Clustered indexes **sort** and store the **data rows** in the table or view based on their key values. These are the columns included in the index definition. There can be only **one clustered index per table**, because the data **rows** themselves can be **stored in only one order**.

Comment: Your reply fits so well in [this meme](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DvXFSZJUcAAVnua.jpg) 

Answer (score 5):

**Clustered Index**

Clustered indexes sort and store the data rows in the table or view based on their key values. These are the columns included in the index definition. There can be only one clustered index per table, because the data rows themselves can be sorted in only one order.

The only time the data rows in a table are stored in sorted order is when the table contains a clustered index. When a table has a clustered index, the table is called a clustered table. If a table has no clustered index, its data rows are stored in an unordered structure called a heap.

**Nonclustered**

Nonclustered indexes have a structure separate from the data rows. A nonclustered index contains the nonclustered index key values and each key value entry has a pointer to the data row that contains the key value.
The pointer from an index row in a nonclustered index to a data row is called a row locator. The structure of the row locator depends on whether the data pages are stored in a heap or a clustered table. For a heap, a row locator is a pointer to the row. For a clustered table, the row locator is the clustered index key.

You can add nonkey columns to the leaf level of the nonclustered index to by-pass existing index key limits, and execute fully covered, indexed, queries. For more information, see Create Indexes with Included Columns. For details about index key limits see Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described

Answer (score 5):

Let me offer a textbook definition on "clustering index", which is taken from 15.6.1 from [Database Systems: The Complete Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873253):

> We may also speak of *clustering indexes*, which are indexes on an attribute or attributes such that all of tuples with a fixed value for the search key of this index appear on roughly as few blocks as can hold them.

To understand the definition, let's take a look at Example 15.10 provided by the textbook:

> A relation `R(a,b)` that is sorted on attribute `a` and stored in that
>   order, packed into blocks, is surely clusterd. An index on `a` is a
>   clustering index, since for a given `a`-value a1, all the tuples with
>   that value for `a` are consecutive. They thus appear packed into
>   blocks, execept possibly for the first and last blocks that contain
>   `a`-value a1, as suggested in Fig.15.14. However, an index on b is
>   unlikely to be clustering, since the tuples with a fixed `b`-value
>   will be spread all over the file unless the values of `a` and `b` are
>   very closely correlated.

[image: Fig 15.14]

Note that the definition does not enforce the data blocks have to be contiguous on the disk; it only says tuples with the search key are packed into as few data blocks as possible.

A related concept is *clustered relation*. A relation is "clustered" if its tuples are packed into roughly as few blocks as can possibly hold those tuples. In other words, from a disk block perspective, if it contains tuples from different relations, then those relations cannot be clustered (i.e., there is a more packed way to store such relation by swapping the tuples of that relation from other disk blocks with the tuples the doesn't belong to the relation in the current disk block). Clearly, `R(a,b)` in example above is clustered.

To connect two concepts together, a clustered relation can have a clustering index and nonclustering index. However, for non-clustered relation, clustering index is not possible unless the index is built on top of the primary key of the relation.

"Cluster" as a word is spammed across all abstraction levels of database storage side (three levels of abstraction: tuples, blocks, file). A concept called "[clustered file](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/554/Syllabus/2-disks/fixed-size.html#clustered)", which describes whether a file (an abstraction for a group of blocks (one or more disk blocks)) contains tuples from one relation or different relations. It doesn't relate to the clustering index concept as it is on file level.

However, some [teaching material](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/554/Syllabus/4-query-exec/index=intro2.html) likes to define clustering index based on the clustered file definition. Those two types of definitions are the same on clustered relation level, no matter whether they define clustered relation in terms of data disk block or file. From the link in this paragraph,

> An index on attribute(s) A on a file is a clustering index when: All tuples with attribute value A = a are stored sequentially (= consecutively) in the data file

Storing tuples consecutively is the same as saying "tuples are packed into roughly as few blocks as can possibly hold those tuples" (with minor difference on one talking about file, the other talking about disk). It's because storing tuple consecutively is the way to achieve "packed into roughly as few blocks as can possibly hold those tuples".

Answer (score 3):

**Clustered Index:**
Primary Key constraint creates clustered Index automatically if no clustered Index already exists on the table. Actual data of clustered index can be stored at leaf level of Index.

**Non Clustered Index:**
Actual data of non clustered index is not directly found at leaf node, instead it has to take an additional step to find because it has only values of row locators pointing towards actual data.
Non clustered Index can't be sorted as clustered index. There can be multiple non clustered indexes per table, actually it depends on the sql server version we are using. Basically Sql server 2005 allows 249 Non Clustered Indexes and for above versions like 2008, 2016 it allows 999 Non Clustered Indexes per table.

Answer (score 3):

**Clustered Index** - A clustered index defines the order in which data is physically stored in a table. Table data can be sorted in only way, therefore, there can be only one clustered index per table. In SQL Server, the primary key constraint automatically creates a clustered index on that particular column.

**Non-Clustered Index** - A non-clustered index doesn’t sort the physical data inside the table. In fact, a non-clustered index is stored at one place and table data is stored in another place. This is similar to a textbook where the book content is located in one place and the index is located in another. This allows for more than one non-clustered index per table.It is important to mention here that inside the table the data will be sorted by a clustered index. However, inside the non-clustered index data is stored in the specified order. The index contains column values on which the index is created and the address of the record that the column value belongs to.When a query is issued against a column on which the index is created, the database will first go to the index and look for the address of the corresponding row in the table. It will then go to that row address and fetch other column values. It is due to this additional step that non-clustered indexes are slower than clustered indexes

**Differences between clustered and Non-clustered index**

1. There can be only one clustered index per table. However, you can
   create multiple non-clustered indexes on a single table.
2. Clustered indexes only sort tables. Therefore, they do not consume
   extra storage. Non-clustered indexes are stored in a separate place
   from the actual table claiming more storage space.
3. Clustered indexes are faster than non-clustered indexes since they
   don’t involve any extra lookup step.

For more information refer to [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-the-difference-between-clustered-and-non-clustered-indexes-in-sql-server/) article.