# Clustered vs Non-Clustered

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, indexing

My lower level knowledge of SQL (Server 2008) is limited, and is now being challanged by our DBAs. Let me explain (I have mentioned obvious statements in the hope that I am right, but if you see something wrong, please tell me) the scenario:

We have a table which holds 'Court Orders' for people. When I created the table, (Name: CourtOrder), I created it like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CourtOrder
(
  CourtOrderID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), (Primary Key)
  PersonId INT NOT NULL,
  + around 20 other fields of different types.
)
```

I then applied a non-clustered index to the primary key (for efficiency). My reasons is that it is a unique field (primary key), and should be indexed, mainly for selection purposes, as we often `Select from table where primary key = ...`

I then applied a CLUSTERED index on PersonId. The reason was to group orders for a particular person physically, as the vast majority of work is getting orders for a person. So, `select from mytable where personId = ...`

I have been pulled up on this now. I have been told that we should put the clustered index on the primary key, and the normal index on the personId. That seems very strange to me. First off, why would you put a clustered index on a unique column? what is it clustering? Surely that's a waste of the clustered index? I'd have believed a normal index would be used on a unique column. Also, clustering the index would mean we can't cluster a different column (One per table, right?).

The reasoning for me being told I have made a mistake is that they believe putting a clustered index on the PersonId would make inserts slow. For the 5% gain in speed of a select, we would be getting a 95% degradation in speed on inserts and updates. Is that correct and valid?

They say that because we cluster the personId, SQL Server has to rearrange data when ever we insert or make a change to the PersonId.

So then I have asked, why would SQL have the concept of a CLUSTERED INDEX, if it's so slow? Is it as slow as they're saying? How should I have setup my indexes to achieve optimum performance? I'd have thought SELECT is used more than INSERT... but they say that we're having locking issues on INSERTS...

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do Clustered and Non clustered index actually mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The distinction between a clustered vs. non-clustered index is that the clustered index *determines the physical order of the rows in the database*. In other words, applying the clustered index to `PersonId` means that the rows will be physically sorted by `PersonId` in the table, allowing an index search on this to go straight to the row (rather than a non-clustered index, which would direct you to the row's location, adding an extra step).

That said, it's *unusual* for the primary key not to be the clustered index, but not unheard of. The issue with your scenario is actually the opposite of what you're assuming: you want *unique* values in a clustered index, not duplicates. Because the clustered index determines the physical order of the row, if the index is on a non-unique column, then the server has to add a background value to rows who have a duplicate key value (in your case, any rows with the same `PersonId`) so that the combined value (key + background value) is unique.

The only thing I would suggest is *not* using a surrogate key (your `CourtOrderId`) column as the primary key, but instead use a compound primary key of the `PersonId` and some other uniquely-identifying column or set of columns. If that's not possible (or not practical), though, then put the clustered index on `CourtOrderId`.

Comment: Thanks Adam. So, when would a clustered index be useful then? I thought the benefit was to clustered index was to group the data, for times when, for example, most queries are on a PersonID ... so the data would be grouped.

Comment: It is **not** physically sorted by `PersonId`. It is logically sorted by `PersonId`, any discrepancy between logical and physical order is the degree of logical fragmentation.

Comment: @cdotlister The benefit of an index is to *sort* the data, not group it (which implied duplicated data within the index). While the distinction might seem semantic, in the case of clustered indexes it is not. If possible, the clustered index should be on something that uniquely identifies the row, and (ideally) is also the most commonly queried column or set of columns. This is why it's *usually* on the primary key.

Comment: Would you want a clustered index for rows that are constantly added and deleted? ;)

Comment: @CyberSluethOmega: I don't know; your question doesn't contain enough information for me to make a decision. Would I want a clustered index on a set of columns where rows would be frequently added or deleted *other than at the end of the table*? No. But I'm not really sure why you're asking that or why the downvote.

Comment: No problem... I'll give you an up vote back.  I was discussing using clustered indexes in situations where data is constantly added and deleted and that would be potentially a bad situation for clustered index as you stated you knew of no situation where a clustered index would not be used.  The reason is b/c the undeleted items in the clustered index would have to be re-arranged to be perfectly clustered together which means one row physically one after the other on the hard drive which would be very in-efficient.

Comment: @CyberSluethOmega: Where did I say that I knew of no situation where a clustered index wouldn't be used? I said that the clustered index is usually on the primary key, and it is.

Comment: Adam I added one point to your comment.  I couldn't add a point back to your answer.   Perhaps in another life when you re-answer this question I can add that point back to your answer instead of just your comment.  I hope this is sufficient. Plus I believe you and I are both more knowledgeable now that we know that there are situations where a clustered index should not be used.  Feel free to add a point to this comment.

Comment: @CyberSluethOmega: The internet can make comments sound defensive or cold when they aren't intended that way. You claimed that I said that I knew of no circumstances where making the clustered index something other than the primary key, when in fact I said no such thing. In fact, what I said was "this is *unusual*..., but not unheard of", which means that I *do* know of cases where this is done.

Comment: Sorry, in my mind I saw this, "I know of no situation where you wouldn't use a clustered index."  But now I don't see that statement.  So based on what I see now you are absolutely correct and you do deserve the point back, however the system does not allow me to change b/c its locked in so I have given you two points back to make up for the difference.  My apologies.

Comment: @AdamRobinson - Thanks for a nice explanation, but I thought your last advice sounded strange; *"..stick with what you have and leave the clustered index on `PersonId`"*. Based on the rest of what you say (and on Darian's example below), wouldn't it either way be best to turn the `PersonId` index into a *non-clustered* one?

Comment: @Sphinxxx: Thanks, that must have been a typo. I've changed it.

Answer (score 15):

I am by no means a SQL Expert...so take this as a developer's view rather than a DBA view..

Inserts on clustered (physically ordered) indexes that aren't in sequential order cause extra work for inserts/updates. Also, if you have many inserts happening at once and they are all occurring in the same location, you end up with contention. Your specific performance varies based on your data and how you access it. The general rule of thumb is to build your clustered index on the most unique narrow value in your table (typically the PK)

I'm assuming your PersonId won't be changing, so Updates don't come into play here. But consider a snapshot of a few rows with PersonId of
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
7
8
8

Now insert 20 new rows for PersonId of 3. First, since this is not a unique key, the server adds some extra bytes to your value (behind the scenes) to make it unique (which also adds extra space) and then the location where these will reside has to be altered.  Compare that to inserting an auto-incrementing PK where the inserts happen at the end.  The non technical explanation would likely come down to this:  there is less 'leaf-shuffling' work to do if it's naturally progressing higher values at the end of the table versus reworking location of the existing items at that location while inserting your items.

Now, if you are having issues with Inserts then you are likely inserting a bunch of the same (or similar) PersonId values at once which is causing this extra work in various places throughout the table and the fragmentation is killing you. The downside of switching to the PK being clustered in your case, is if you are having insert issues today on PersonIds that vary in value spread throughout the table, if you switch your clustered index to the PK and all of the inserts now happen in one location then your problem may actually get worse due to increased contention concentration.  (On the flip side, if your inserts today are not spread out all over, but are all typically bunched in similar areas, then your problem will likely ease by switching your clustered index away from PersonId to your PK because you'll be minimizing the fragmentation.)

Your performance problems should be analyzed to your unique situation and take these types of answers as general guidelines only. Your best bet is to rely on a DBA that can validate exactly where your problems lie. It sounds like you have resource contention issues that may be beyond a simple index tweak. This could be a symptom of a much larger problem. (Likely design issues...otherwise resource limitations.)

In any case, good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Some authors do suggest not "wasting" the `CI` on an `identity` column if there is an alternative that would benefit range queries.

From MSDN [Clustered Index Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639.aspx) the key should be chosen according to the following criteria

1. Can be used for frequently used queries.
2. Provide a high degree of uniqueness.
3. Can be used in range queries.

Your `CourtOrderID` column meets `2`. Your `PersonId` meets `1` and `3`. As most rows will end up with the `uniqueifier` added anyway you might as well just declare it as unique and use `PersonId,CourtOrderID` as this will be the same width but be more useful as the clustered index key is added to all NCIs as the row locator and this will allow them to cover more queries.

The main issue with using `PersonId,CourtOrderID` as the CI is that logical fragmentation will likely ensue (and this particularly affects the range queries you are trying to help) so you would need to monitor fill factor, and fragmentation levels and perform index maintenance more often.

Answer (score 3):

It's explained in the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms190457.aspx

**Clustered**

- Clustered indexes *sort and store the data rows in the table or view* based on their key values. These are the columns included in the index definition. There can be only one clustered index per table, because the data rows themselves can be sorted in only one order.
- The only time the data rows in a table are stored in sorted order is when the table contains a clustered index. When a table has a clustered index, the table is called a clustered table. If a table has no clustered index, its data rows are stored in an unordered structure called a heap.

**Nonclustered**

- Nonclustered indexes have a structure separate from the data rows. A nonclustered index c*ontains the nonclustered index key values and each key value entry has a pointer to the data row that contains the key value*.
- The pointer from an index row in a nonclustered index to a data row is called a row locator. The structure of the row locator depends on whether the data pages are stored in a heap or a clustered table. For a heap, a row locator is a pointer to the row. For a clustered table, the row locator is the clustered index key.
- You can add nonkey columns to the leaf level of the nonclustered index to by-pass existing index key limits, 900 bytes and 16 key columns, and execute fully covered, indexed, queries.

Answer (score -3):

Some db with some nasty selects, joins in a stored procedure - only diffrence is the index

INDEXES - clustered vs nonclustered

```
  891 rows
  10 sec
  NONCLUSTERED 

  OR

  891 rows
  14 sec
  CLUSTERED
```