# Is a table sorted by primary key in a Edit mode?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, ssms

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio and I have a table with a primary key which is a combination of letters and numbers.

My co-woker inserted all primary keys and now she wants to start inserting data, so she asked me if I can resave the data so that the table is sorted by its primary key. But I was thinking that it should be already sorted??

So, my question is ...

When I right-click the table and select "Edit Top XXX Rows", is the table already sorted by its primary key?

Comment: if primary key is a clustered index, there are good probability of table will be sorted on it, but server does not guarantee it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be seeing the editable rows, sorted by the clustered index, which is generally the primary key, but could be more. More information on Clustered vs Non-Clustered Indexes can be found in this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605707/clustered-vs-non-clustered).

Also, you can manually change the SQL Select Statement that is being executed in order to present the editable rows. Follow the simple instructions from this [blog post](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/11/04/visually-edit-records-for-any-query-using-sql-management-studio), and you will be able to view the rows, ordered by which ever column you desire.

Hope this was helpful!

CSharpie

Answer (score -2):

Yes,  It will be sorted by primary key only if the primary key is also the [CLUSTERING KEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but possible reason is that what you saying is not a promise. See here http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx