# Optimizing queries based on clustered and non-clustered indexes in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I have been reading lately about how `clustered index` and `non-clustered index` works. My understanding in simple terms (correct me if wrong):

The data structure that backs `clustered` and `non-clustered index` is `B-Tree`

`Clustered Index`: physically sorts the data based on the index column (or key). you can have only one `clustered Index` per `table`. If no `index` is specified during table creation, `SQL` server will automatically create a `clustered Index` on the `primary key column`.

**Q1**: Since data is physically sorted based on index, there is no extra space needed here. is this correct? so what happens when I drop the index I created?

`Non-clustered Index`: In `non-clustered indexes`, the `leaf-node` of the tree contains the columns values and a pointer (row locator) to the actual row in the database. Here there is extra space needed for storing this `non-clustered index table` physically on disk. However, one is not limited by the number of `non-clustered Indexes.`

**Q2**: Does it mean a query on non-clustered index column will not result in the sorted data?

**Q3**: There is an extra look-up associated here to locate the actual row data using the pointer at the leaf node. How much performance difference would this be when compared to a clustered index?

Excercise:

consider an Employee table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
PersonID int PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar(255),
age int,
salary int
);
```

Now I created an employee table ( a default clustered index on employee is created).

Two frequent queries on this table happen only on age and salary columns. For sake of simplicity,
lets assume that the table is NOT frequently updated

for example:

```
select * from employee where age > XXX;

select * from employee where salary > XXXX and salary < YYYY;
```

**Q4** : what is the best way to construct indexes, so that queries on both these column have similar performance.  If I have clustered index on age queries on age column will be faster but than on salary column will be slower.

**Q5**:  On a related note, I have repeatedly seen that indexes (both clustered and non-clustered) should be created on column with unique constraints. why is that? what will happen on failure to do this?

Thank you very much
Posts I read are here:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/08/difference-between-clustered-index-and-nonclustered-index-sql-server-database.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx

[Clustered vs Non-Clustered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605707/clustered-vs-non-clustered)

[What do Clustered and Non clustered index actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean?rq=1)

[What are the differences between a clustered and a non-clustered index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91688/what-are-the-differences-between-a-clustered-and-a-non-clustered-index?lq=1)

[How does database indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work?lq=1)

Comment: You tagged this question [tag:mysql], but your questions imply that you are asking about Microsoft SQL Server. Which is it? Both products provide clustered and non-clustered indexes, but the internal details may differ slightly. Can you please clarify, and if necessary edit the tags?

Comment: @BillKarwin: I am not asking about Microsoft SQl server. I want this to be a general question. The interal implementation of indexes might differ between mysql and Microsoft's. but I am interested in the concept/idea of how it works. I am not sure what part of question specifies Microsoft SQL server if so, kindly edit it. I am a beginner here, so I might have interchanged terminologies unknowingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server

**Q1** Extra space is only needed for the clustered index if it is not unique. SQL Server will add a 4 byte uniquifier internally to a non-unique clustered index. This is because it uses the cluster key as a rowid in non-clustered indexes.

**Q2** A non-clustered index can be read in order. That may aid queries where you specify an order. It may also make merge joins attractive. It will also help with range queries (x < col and y > col).

**Q3** SQL Server does an extra "bookmark lookup" when using a non-clustered index. But, this is only if it needs a column that isn't in the index. Note also, that you can `include` extra columns in the leaf level of indexs. If an index can be used without the additional lookup it is called a covering index.

If a bookmark lookup is required, it doesn't take a high percentage of rows until it's quicker just to scan the whole clustered index. The level depends on row size, key size etc. But 5% of rows is a typical cut off.

**Q4** If the most important thing in your application was making both these queries as fast as possible, you could create covering index on both of them:

```
create index IX_1 on employee (age) include (name, salary);
create index IX_2 on employee (salary) include (name, age);
```

Note you don't have to specifically include the cluster key, as the non-clustered index has it as the row pointer.

**Q5** This is more important for cluster keys than non-cluster keys due to the uniquifier. The real issue though is whether an index is selective or not for your queries. Imagine an index on a `bit` value. Unless the distribution of data is very skewed, such an index is unlikely to be used for anything.

---

More info about the uniquifier. Imagine you and a non unique clustered index on age, and a non-clustered index on salary. Say you had the following rows:

```
age | salary | uniqifier
20  | 1000   | 1
20  | 2000   | 2
```

Then the salary index would locate rows like so

```
1000 -> 20, 1
2000 -> 20, 2
```

Say you ran the query `select * from employee where salary = 1000`, and the optimizer chose to use the salary index. It would then find the pair (20, 1) from the index lookup, then lookup this value in the main data.

Comment: Thks for taking effort to help here. can you please elaborate your point for Q1. Regarding Q2) select query on a non-clustered index will result in sorted order only if I specify `ORDER BY`. (From above So answer). On a clustered-index, it is sorted by default. so there is an extra "sorting" process in-case of non-clustered indexes correct? so a range operation (`age < 30 and age > 60`) is going to be ineffective in non-clustered indexes. please explain

Comment: +1 good to give examples of how Microsoft differs from MySQL. Index implementations are not universal. In fact, the ANSI/ISO SQL standard doesn't mention indexes at all, so all implementations are vendor extensions to SQL!

Comment: a non clustered index is still a b-tree, so you can read the index pages in order. Imagine if you wanted to know how many people were aged between 10 and 20. You would find 10 in the btree, and then traverse in order until you got to 20, counting each row as you pass.

Comment: Q1) how is that uniquifier that SQL server adds helps in locating that row? for example, in my example above, I created a clustered index on age (which is not unique). now when I execute query, `select * from employee where age=20;` since there are many employee with age 20, how it retrieves all the data

Comment: I've put some more information about the uniqifier at the end.

Comment: great example. Thanks. when I query on CLUSTERED INDEX, which is age in the example you provided, `select * from employee where age=20`. The b-tree search will happen till the leaf node. Now at the leaf node, there are two rows with age=20. will both be returned?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about internals of Microsoft SQL Server, but I can answer for MySQL, which you tagged for your question. The details could vary for other implementations.

**Q1.** Right, no extra space is needed for the clustered index.

What happens if you drop the clustered index? MySQL's InnoDB engine always uses the primary key (or the first non-null unique key) as the clustered index. If you define a table without a primary key, or you drop the primary key of an existing table, [InnoDB generates an internal artificial key for the clustered index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html). This internal key has no logical column to reference it.

**Q2.** A order of rows returned by a query that uses a non-clustered index is not guaranteed. In practice, it's the order in which the rows were accessed. If you need rows to be returned in a specific order, you should use `ORDER BY` in your query. If the optimizer can infer that your desired order is the same as the order in which it will access rows (index order, whether by clustered or non-clustered index), then it can skip the sorting step.

**Q3.** InnoDB non-clustered index does not have a pointer to the corresponding row at a leaf of the index, it has the *value* of the primary key. So a lookup in a non-clustered index is really two B-tree searches, the first to find the leaf of the non-clustered index, and then a second search in the clustered index.

This is double the cost of a single B-tree search (more or less), so InnoDB has an extra feature called the [Adaptive Hash Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-adaptive-hash.html). Frequently-searched values get cached in the AHI, and the next time a query searches for a cached value, it can do an O(1) lookup. In the AHI cache, it finds a pointer directly to the leaf of the clustered index, so it eliminates *both* B-tree searches, part of the time.

How much this improves total performance depends on how frequently you search for the same value(s) that have been searched before. In my experience, it's typical for the ratio of hash searches vs. non-hash searches to be about 1:2.

**Q4.** Construct the indexes to serve the queries you need to be optimized. Typically a clustered index is a primary or unique key, and at least in the case of InnoDB, this is required. Neither `age` nor `salary` is likely to be unique.

You may like my presentation, [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

**Q5.** InnoDB automatically creates an index when you declare a unique constraint. You can't have the constraint without an index existing for it. If you didn't have an index, how would the engine ensure uniqueness when you insert a value? It would need to search the entire table for a duplicate value in that column. The index helps to make unique checks much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. regarding Q3: you mentioned two b-tree searches will be made, But to find the right row, I will have three block reads (and each block might have 10-rows to 100 depending on block size). So in theory, even thought I have the ID of primary key, I need to read the entire block, skip through till I find the ID of interest. Is this correct?

Comment: if you have youtube or any video presentation of your talk, that would be great. I am looking at slides and they are just awesome!!

Comment: Correct. InnoDB for example stores everything in uniformly-sized pages (16KB by default). Some number of rows fit within one page. But once it loads the page into memory, the overhead of searching it is negligible. The I/O for loading the page from disk is about 100,000 times more expensive.

Comment: It seems my talk was recorded by ZendCon when I presented it there in 2012. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Comment: Thanks for the video. will watch it soon. Regarding Q4 and Q5). if in my table, only my primary key is unique, clustered index will work only on pk (meaning I cannot have clustered index on any other column. Is that applicable to non-clustered index too). That looks like a severe limitation given the fact queries such as `select name from Employee e where e.id =434534` are rare (not useful) as compared to `select name from employee e where e.name="Mike"`

Comment: If you want to exploit the performance advantage of the clustered index, then use `name` as your primary key. Or a compound key like `(name, emp_id)`. A primary key doesn't have to be a single column, and doesn't have to be an integer. Or perhaps you use a different RDBMS that doesn't have the restriction that MySQL has, and instead [allows you to define a non-primary key column as your clustered index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-cluster.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61143/discussion-between-brain-storm-and-bill-karwin).

Comment: So suppose I have a table with auto-increasing integer as primary key, a name (which is not unique), and a value corresponding to it. I need to search the table by the non-unique name string (2nd column). If I form a non-clustered index on this column, will searching by this column be faster? If so, at what cost? If not so, then how do I make it faster? Some info - further data added will have 2nd column name that is not always increasing, unlike the primary key..

Comment: @AttitudeMonger, searching by an index is faster than searching without an index. The benefit is greater the more rows you have in the table. It makes no difference if the data is increasing or not, the DBMS software takes care of inserting into the index in sorted order.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Another question - imagine the same table with no primary key. There are two columns - one is is serial number, and one is URL. Serial numbers can repeat, but the URLs will not. I will need to search by both serial number (like get all URLs for a given serial no.) as well as URL (find if a URL is there). So will it make sense to create two indices for this table - a unique index on the URL and a non-unique index on the serial number?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger For best performance, create a single index with two columns. This is getting way off topic for this answer. Go watch my presentation "How to Design Indexes, Really" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU