# Is there possibility to solve this with index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Problem is that index as is. I can't alter or add it.

Can I do something for better query plan?

Index on 2 columns: `pid`, `Date`.

But `select` is only on `Date`...

Table `deal` is very big (>1 000 000 rows)

```
create table deal
(
    Id  Int,           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    pid Int,           NOT NULL,
    Date              smalldatetime NOT NULL
)

create clustered index pk ON deal (pid, Date)

select * 
from deal 
where Date between @d1 and @d2
```

Comment: Can you change the order of the index `(Date,Pid)` ?

Comment: Add a separate index on just `Date` (BTW: it's a **really bad idea** to use reserved SQL Server keywords like `Date` as column names - use something **more meaningful** to your problem domain, e.g.  'DealDate` or whatever!). How many rows out of those 1 million or more does a single `date` value return??

Comment: "deal is very big (>1 000 000 rows)"... that's not very big...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ID as your clustered index and create a second index on date including ID and PID (Covering Index).  If you do batch inserts then drop the date index and recreate it after to improve insert performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would create my clustered index over id and create a non clustered index over date like this

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX noncluxidxdate ON deal (Date)
INCLUDE (id, pid);
```

this post will help you understand
[What do Clustered and Non clustered index actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean)