# How do SQL Server unique constraints work?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a SQL Server table with a column specified with a unique constraint. When doing frequent inserts into that table, how does this constraint get enforced; does SQL Server check the entire table? Does an attempt to insert a duplicate row mean it creates a deadlock, or does it only return an error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL SERVER: Unique Constraint Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072855/sql-server-unique-constraint-explanation)

Comment: Not exact, does unique constraints create deadlock issue? While insert duplicate row means.

Comment: A constraint does not "create deadlock issues". It is your code, your transaction boundaries, and the order of locks taken during the execution of your queries that can lead to deadlock.

Comment: Constraints always create errors when inserting invalid data (be either with unique indexes, foreing keys and checks). They don't produce by themselves deadlocks.