# Cluster or unique index MySql DB?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have one interesting question: what is difference between cluster index and unique index? What's better and faster and why?

Comment: Have you read e.g. [What do Clustered and Non clustered index actually mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean) or the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html)? If no, do it now. If yes: there is no "better" (especially not without a "for what"). But you should know this by now. If you have a more specific question, you should ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL's InnoDB engine, you get 3 choices of ordinary indexes:

- `PRIMARY KEY` -- "clustered" with the data and "unique".  (Often `AUTO_INCREMENT`)
- `UNIQUE` -- unique, not clustered.
- `INDEX` -- non unique, not clustered.

All are implemented as BTrees.  Clustered means that the data is in the leaf node.

Considerations:

- Any of the 3 choices can help with performance of searching for row(s).* InnoDB needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.
- If you want the database to spit at you when you are trying to insert something that is already there, you need to specify the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE`.
- Secondary keys (`UNIQUE` or `INDEX`) go through the `PRIMARY KEY` to find the data.  Corollary 1:  Finding a row by the PK is faster.  Corollary 2:  A bulky (eg, `VARCHAR(255)`) PK is an extra burden on every secondary key.
- A "covering" secondary key does not need to go beyond its BTree.
- Data and indexes are cached in RAM at the 16KB block unit; caching *may* be an important consideration in performance.
- UUID/GUID indexes are terrible when the index cannot be fully cached -- due to high I/O.
- An `INSERT` must immediately check the `PRIMARY KEY` and any `UNIQUE` key(s) for duplicate, but it can delay updating other secondary keys.  (This *may* have impact on performance during inserts.)

From those details, it is sometimes possible to deduce the answers to your questions.

(Caveat: Engines other than InnoDB have some different characteristics.)