# Non-clustered index contains copies of physical data or just positions to physical data ?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Non-clustered index contains copies of physical data or just positions to physical data ?

Comment: I literally copy/pasted your question into google, and the first result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean

Comment: positions of Physical data which are pointed to clustered Index where the actual data will be there along with Clustering Keys

Comment: Thanks everyone !