# Query Optimization (MySql/Sql) : Moving functions out of where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, where-clause

UPDATE : For anyone reading this , as @dnoeth  stated below indexing makes a huge difference when it comes to query time. In some cases it cut row scans down to 1 row.  You just have to pick the flavor of indexing that suits you best . [Clustered vs Non Clustered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean)

Index example:

```
E.g: create index ix_descr on my_db.media (description asc)
```

---

I have a query that is taking a long time to run, it has has quite a number of functions in the where clause. What is the best approach to optimizing my query ?

Moving functions out of where clause and replacing them with joins,etc ?

I've given a few simple examples below, **FIG 2** and **3** are my optimatization attempts, let me know your thoughts.

**Note* these aren't the actual functions I am using, I use dbo.DecryptBlob(m.mediaId) etc.  I chose to use the functions below to make the question easier to grasp.**

**FIG 1.)**

```
SELECT 
    description, id
FROM
    my_db.media
where 
    length(description) = 10
    and description like "S%"
    and trim(left(m.description,2)) = 'St'
```

---

POSSIBLE OPTIMIZATIONS

**FIG 2.)** (Using join and group by)

```
SELECT
    m.description, m.mediaId
FROM
    my_db.media m
        inner JOIN
    my_db.media m1 ON length(m.description) = 10 
        and m.description like "S%"
        and trim(left(m.description,2)) = 'St'
group by m.mediaId
```

**FIG 3.)** (Using join and distinct)

```
SELECT distinct
    m.description, m.mediaId
FROM
    my_db.media m
        inner JOIN
    my_db.media m1 ON length(m.description) = 10 
        and m.description like "S%"
        and trim(left(m.description,2)) = 'St'
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? Please elaborate . Should I phrase my question differently  so it elicits more of an answer rather than opinions ?

Comment: You can try https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: Adding a self-join increases complexity, it doesn't matter if a condition is palced in WHERE or ON, I doubt there's improvement, should be way less efficient. Better *index* your data. Btw, you can remove `LENGTH` and the stupid `TRIM(LEFT)` and simplify to a single condition: `WHERE description like "St________"`

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your starting comment I phrase as "Don't hide an indexed column inside a function, the Optimizer can't find it to use the `INDEX`."

```
and description like "S%"
and trim(left(m.description,2)) = 'St'
```

is the same as

```
and description LIKE "St%"
```

With that, `INDEX(description)` will work nicely.  The check for length=10 is secondary, and not a real problem.  It will do a "range" scan of that index.  (If you did not mean '2' and 'St', then my comment *may not* apply.)

`TRIM` -- Clean up the input rather than trying to do it during the `SELECT`.

In this situation, using a `JOIN` will show things down.

It is "wrong" to do `group by m.mediaId` without specifying `mediaId` in the `SELECT` list.  So, I don't know what you were aiming at in Fig.2.

Comment: What if I have no choice but to use a function on an indexed column say  dbo.DecryptBlob(clientId) etc, what the best work around for a case like that ?

Comment: "dbo"?  This is MySQL.

Comment: yes that is correct, lets say for syntax and semantics purpose we have the MySQL equivalent of dbo.DecryptBlob(),  what work around could I use in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If your application frequently selects by the length of the description, you should consider adding a column that contains the length of the description and creating an index on it.

Comment: I more so asking about the best way to tackle moving functions  out of a where clause, whether it more beneficial to do joins, index etc. @Dnoeth noted that joins increase the complexity of the query, I removed the join and indexed the columns and noticed and increase in performance.

Comment: Sometimes people are very focussed on the solutions that jump out at them, and don't step back and look at other possibilities. In general if people come across this thread I wanted to point out that the options you were considering are not the only ways to solve this type of performance problem.