# Must the search key of a primary index be or related to the primary key?

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/51087864/3284469

> primary keys can be primary indices.

Must the search key of a primary index be or related to a primary key ? Will the answer be different in PostgreSQL and other DBMS? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Indexes are not part of standard SQL & depend on the particular DBMS. What did you learn researching in the manual? What part of that other question is relevant?--please make this & all questions self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres doesn't have "primary index", all indexes are implemented the same way, and point directly to the data rows.

> Must the search key of a primary index be or related to a primary key

It must be a search on the expression used to form the primary index.
if the primary index is constrained to be an index on the primary key then `yes` else `no`.

> Will the answer be different in PostgreSQL and other DBMS?

yes, because postgresql does not have primary index.  although a clustered index is a bit like a primary index. the clustered index can be an index on on any expression, it need not reference the primary key at all.

with postgreql there is no requirement that a table have any index. but if you want to define relations between tables then indexes are required.

Comment: Mostly agree, but there is no clustered index in PostgreSQL.

Comment: for tables which are not updated subsequent to being clustered there is.

Comment: So you'd call an index that is physically in no way different from any other index, but happens to be sorted just like the table, a clustered index? Then you are right of course.

Comment: the clustering index is remembered by the database so that the table can be re-clustered without specifying the index. in that way the index is different from the others.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "if you want to define relations between tables then indexes are required."?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... ADD ...  REFERENCES ...`

Comment: @Jasen - however, you're not `obliged` to define any indexes on the child field(s). So, the part where you say `if you want to define relations between tables then indexes are required.` would be incorrect - no?