# How do I sort a column from the bottom to the top?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table `videos` with the columns `id` | `position` | `title` now I  want to sort the column `position` from the end to the bottom in a permanent way with e.g. `UPDATE`. I could change that manually but there are more than 460 rows I would have to update manually which is really annoying.

I already tried

```
SELECT position FROM videos ORDER BY position + 0 asc;
```

which shows the needed result but I don't know how to make it a permanent change. If I use

```
UPDATE videos SET position = (SELECT position FROM videos ORDER BY position + 0 asc);
```

which changes the rows of the column to one value.

The table looks like this

```
Id    | position | title
---------------------------
tz7e  | 3        | title1
-cQ6  | 4        | title2
Q1L3  | 1        | title3
y456  | 2        | title4
V2n4  | 5        | title5
p76b  | 7        | title6
98kN  | 6        | title7
```

But it want to have it like that

```
Id    | position | title
---------------------------
tz7e  | 7        | title1
-cQ6  | 6        | title2
Q1L3  | 5        | title3
y456  | 4        | title4
V2n4  | 3        | title5
p76b  | 2        | title6
98kN  | 1        | title7
```

But with 460 entries in the column `position` that I want to rerow.

Comment: shample input and output is helpfull

Comment: Why bother? Reorder rows is a bad idea.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What's the intention of the `+ 0`? Can't you simply use `ORDER BY position ASC`?

Comment: If I use `ORDER BY position asc` the result get sort like this 0,1,10,11,12 and so on but want to have it like 1,2,3,4,5,...

Comment: @jarlh I want to change the value of the column because the titles got mixed up and now I want to get them in the right order as they were before.

Comment: Show us some sample table data - both current and wanted versions. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: "want to have it like 1,2,3,4,5,..."  -  not exactly sure what you want but I think this is a data type issue. Sorting strings that contain numbers is different than sorting numerics.

Comment: Edit: Updated question with example table

Comment: Are you looking to re-order the position based on the order of which they were recorded? what determined the correct order?

Comment: the order before was like the one in the second table if a new row was added the column `position` counted + 1. In the example above there would be a new row which now has the number 1 and the other entries of `position` would get + 1.

Comment: But do you have a datetime recorded when the new value was added? Could you not use this to re-sequence the positions?

Comment: There is no datetime record. I am really lost as there is no solution to rearrange the mixed up entries in the table

Comment: If the idea is to get back to the previous ordering, then unless you have something that determined the orginal sequence, you will have to undertake this manually. In future it is worth structuring the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like what you want is a [Clustered Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251636/what-do-clustered-and-non-clustered-index-actually-mean). Put it on the column Position and the rows will be physically ordered by that column on the disk. The order ascending or descending does not matter in this case.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX name ON videos (position);
```