# What are the difference between clustered and a non-clustered index?

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between a clustered and a non-clustered index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91688/what-are-the-differences-between-a-clustered-and-a-non-clustered-index)

What are the difference between clustered and a non-clustered index?

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91688/what-are-the-differences-between-a-clustered-and-a-non-clustered-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What are the differences between a clustered and a non-clustered index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91688/what-are-the-differences-between-a-clustered-and-a-non-clustered-index/91725#91725)

1. A clustered index is a special type of index that reorders the way records in the table are physically stored. Therefore table can have only one clustered index. The leaf nodes of a clustered index contain the data pages.
2. A non clustered index is a special type of index in which the logical order of the index does not match the physical stored order of the rows on disk. The leaf node of a non clustered index does not consist of the data pages. Instead, the leaf nodes contain index rows.