# Improve performance of a simple SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Contract_Position 
WHERE Position_Type != 'MARKET'
```

Click on the link below to view the image of table of data -

[image: Table of data]

Imagine the scenario where there are now millions of records in `Contract  Position` table, how would you enhance the performance of the above query?

Thanks for your help, 
S

Comment: Please use the following as a guide on how to post a good question: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Hint: data instead of images make a world of a difference... Also, for a question on performance, it would be beneficial to share the execution plan. Use the following tool for this: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: You stated in the comments on one answer that is just a hypothetical question. What are you expecting for an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Have an index on column `Position_Type`.

Comment: Thanks. What type of index?

Comment: You need to share what indexes you already have... just adding an index blindly doesn't always answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Add user defined index on Position_Type column

Comment: That would be a Non clustered index?

Comment: You need to share what indexes you already have... just adding an index blindly doesn't always answer the question

Comment: Sorry, there are no indexes available, this is a hypothetical situation/question. The only data I have is on the image. Is there anything else I can provide to aid the your answer?

Comment: use below link cluster index only one in a table : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91688/what-are-the-differences-between-a-clustered-and-a-non-clustered-index

Answer (score -1):

If index are not sufficient, with for example MariaDB you can partition your table basing on some criterias.

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server so MariaDB is not relevant.

Comment: Which index is the best one to use - 

Clustered or Non-clustered

Comment: clustered are better for performance but it depends on what you have to do

Comment: From the above I was advised to to introduce a index to improve the performance issue. Please advise

Comment: @SatyenGotecha No one can "improve" performance in a hypothetical example. So stop worrying and start doing. If you run into an actual performance problem, that is the time to address it. And note that nothing is free. You need to measure performance across all aspects of your usage. Tuning just one query can easily make others worse. If you are new to this, then you should consult with someone that has the appropriate abilities.